# Angular2 - CKEditor use

Tags: ckeditor, angular

How could I use ckeditor with Angular2 component?

Doing something like:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'e',
  template: `
  <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
      This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
  </textarea>
  <script>
      CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
  </script>
  `
})

export class E {

}
```

and printing it in index.html like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="../systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="../es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="../angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="../rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="../angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="../angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="../angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/spin.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {
          compiled: {
              format: 'register',
              defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('../compiled/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hackathon incoming!
    <e>Loading...</e>
  </body>
</html>
```

doesn't work. It works good when I put all the textarea with script code in index.html but I really want to have it in component template. It's like the ckeditor doesn't see the textarea ID when it is in component.

How can I make ckeditor plugin working good with Angular2 component? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't add the script to your template. use this instead

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

declare const window: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'e',
  template: `
     <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
         This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
     </textarea>
  `
})
export class E {
    constructor(){}
    ngOnInit(){
       if(window.CKEDITOR) {
           window.CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
       }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Check angular2 [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html), and since the components are javascript you can execute any script code from inside your component.

**A better way**,

implement a `CKEDITOR` component that will be used like this

```
<CKEditor [targetId]="editor1" [rows]="10" [cols]="80"> </CKEditor>
```

ckeditor.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

declare const window: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'CKEditor',
  template: `
     <textarea name="targetId" id="targetId" rows="rows" cols="cols">
         This is my CKEditor component.
     </textarea>
  `
})
export class CKEditorComponent {

    @Input() targetId;
    @Input() rows = 10;  //you can also give default values here
    @Input() cols;     

    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit(){
       if(window.CKEDITOR) {
           window.CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
       }
    }
}
```

**The best way**,

Get the typescript definition file for CKEditor, I found it [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d70a5a65a593d412a4743b9b295c7a5cef4ed626/ckeditor/ckeditor.d.ts).
Add it to your project, after that you will be able to use the library.

*this is only for illustrating, not tested.*

```
import * as CKEDITOR from 'CKEDITOR/PATH';   
.
.
ngOnInit(){
   CKEDITOR.replace( targetId );
}
```

Comment: Works great but where exactly have you found this? I'm doing something wrong on angular2 site if I couldn't do it.

Comment: @MurhafSousli will we be using ckeditor definition file by <reference path = "path"> or do we have to import it like you said? need help in using it

Comment: @noor  with webpack you don't need to.

Comment: @MurhafSousli I am not using webpack

Comment: @noor then you should add that line

Comment: @MurhafSousli I am doing it like `/// <reference path="./ckeditor.d.ts" />` but getting error CKEDITOR is not defined in [value in CoursesComponent@54:8] .. how can i use import {CKEditor} from "./ckeditor" here

Comment: @noor I really don't know, but I suggest you use this awesome starter kit https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter it has many supporters, and you can I ask them about anything.

Comment: @noor adding `d.ts` files to your project never been easier with that starter kit, you just need to `typings install yourLibrary` and the definition file is added automatically

Comment: I got the following error: `The editor instance "editor1" is already attached to the provided element.`

Comment: @Murhaf Sousli: how to get this ckeditor value in angular2?

Comment: @BharatChauhan someone had made `CKEditorModule` https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor use that instead

Comment: Hi @Murhaf. Have you encountered an issue like [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48363139/how-to-get-ckeditor-to-work-with-angular-directive)? Could you help? I am trying to get attention of the textarea although it's buried under the ckeditor.