# Angular 2 CKEditor: the editor instance is already attached to the provided element

Tags: forms, angular, ckeditor

I am using the solution explained in the answer of this post [Angular2 - CKEditor use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978025/angular2-ckeditor-use), however I get the following error:

> The editor instance "editor1" is already attached to the provided
>   element.

### UPDATE

#### ckeditor.ts

```
import {Component, Input} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'CKEDITOR',
  template: `
     <textarea name="targetId" id="targetId" rows="rows" cols="cols">
         This is my CKEditor component.
     </textarea>
  `
})
export class Ckeditor {

  @Input() targetId;
  @Input() rows = 10;  //you can also give default values here
  @Input() cols;

  constructor(){}
  ngOnInit(){
    window['CKEDITOR']['replace']( this.targetId );
  }
}
```

#### the template

```
 templateUrl: `<CKEDITOR [targetId]="editor1" [rows]="10" [cols]="80"></CKEDITOR>`,
  directives: [Ckeditor]
```

### UPDATE

I am using a custom ckeditor

```
  <script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>


  System.config({
      packages: {
        app: {
          format: 'register',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        "ng2-ckeditor": {
          "defaultExtension": "js"
        }
      }, map: {
        "ng2-ckeditor": "node_modules/ng2-ckeditor/lib/CKEditor.js"
      }
    });
```

Comment: Have you checked if the code that initialized the editor is called more than once for whatever reason? Please add some code that demonstrates what you have tried.

Comment: Does your application contain more than one instance of your `Ckeditor` component? Is your `Ckeditor` component (or one of its ancestors) added by the router or ony added statically?

Comment: I have updated the question. I used indeed `<CKEDITOR [targetId]="editor1" [rows]="10" [cols]="80"></CKEDITOR>` 2 times but now I get a different error: `Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined`

Comment: Just a wild guess: Change `ngOnInit()` to `ngAfterViewInit()` otherwise I have no idea. Are there more details with the error message (stack trace, ...)?

Comment: Still the same error: `Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined
    at a (ckeditor.js:325)
    at Object.CKEDITOR.replace (ckeditor.js:329)
    at Ckeditor.ngAfterViewInit (ckeditor.ts:13)`

Comment: maybe this more clearly http://imgur.com/WtWJnPM